# How to fix "could not find driver" for SQLite on windows

Tags: php, laravel-8

I want to use SQLite on laravel so I try to use

`php .\artisan migrate`

and it give me an error

` Illuminate\Database\QueryException

could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)
`

so I try to download sqlite3.dll from sqlite on https://www.sqlite.org/download.html
and add sqlite3.dll PHP/ext and it give me an other error

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Can't load module 'C:\PHP\ext\sqlite3.DLL' as it's linked with 9.0, but the core is linked with 14.29 in Unknown on line 0`

How can i fix this problem?
thanks !

PHP 8.2.3
laravel 8.x
windows 10

How can i fix this problem?
I find the solution on internet but almost are develop on Linux.
thanks !

Comment: Did you also changed the `php.ini` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check the phpinfo();
you can see PDO make sure there have the sql driver you use.
if not add

```
extension=pdo_sqlite
```

in php.ini
it work for me !
Good luck

Comment: This is also the solution for Laravel 11 dev-master on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that, SQLite extension is **enabled** in your PHP installation. To check use :
`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`